# php informaçoes do browser e sistema operacional

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet

preciso de uma ajuda com alguma biblioteca que detecta o sistema operacional e o browser utilizado pelo cliente, pesquisei muito na net e não achei nada que valesse a pena, somente um monte de emaranhado de código que retorna nada!

apenas uma biblioteca que eu achei, e ate agora parece ser mais completa porem eu nao consegui carregar ela de jeito algum, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor?

[Device-detector](https://github.com/piwik/device-detector)

Comment: Cheque [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070154/get-operating-system-info-with-php) resposta. Mesmo se você não conhece inglês, o código postado é relevante...

Comment: Genos, sua resposta ja ajudou demais, nao e uma biblioteca pronta mas estou pensando em criar uma bem mais complexa a partir das respostas em ingles, eu tentei usar o user_agent mas eu teria que criar o resto do 0 e nao estou com muito tempo para isso , por isso esta atras de uma biblioteca pronta, mas esta resposta ja ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com este [artigo](http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/05/detect-operating-system-and-detect.html), você só precisa do obter o `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];`.

Para exibir o nome do navegador ou sistema operacional de forma mais legível, ele compara o valor recebido com um array próprio utilizando regex.
Então ao invés de exibir '/netscape/' será exibido 'Netscape'.

http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/05/detect-operating-system-and-detect.html

Comment: boa Marcus, esse array ja adianta bastante o trabalho, pq se tiver que adicionar mais alguma coisa, e só colocar no array!